# How to combine estimator with different variances?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, estimation-theory

Consider independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ that have the same expectation $\mathbb x=\mathbb E[X_1]=\mathbb E[X_2]=\ldots$

Further, assume that we know that $Var[X_i]=\sigma_i^2$.

---

In the simple case where all variances are equal, a common practice is to use the *median trick*:
we can take the average over $h=\frac{4\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$ estimators $Y_i=\frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=1}^h X_{i,j}$, then $Var[Y_i]=\sigma^2/h$, and using Chebyshev's inequality:
$$
\Pr[|Y_i-\mathbb E[Y_i]|\ge \epsilon]\le 1/4.
$$
Next, we take the median over $t=O(\log 1/\delta)$ such $Y_i's$: $Z=Median_{t\in\{1,\ldots,t\}}(Y_k)$ to get that $$\Pr[|Z-\mathbb E[Z]|\ge \epsilon]\le \delta.$$

That is, we needed a total of $O(\sigma^2\epsilon^{-2}\log1/\delta)$ estimators to get an $(\epsilon,\delta)$ guarantee.

---

Now say that we have $\sigma_1\le \sigma_2\le\ldots$ (i.e., we know the variances, but they are not the same):

> **How should we build the estimator to factor in the different variances?**

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\si\sigma \newcommand\ep\epsilon \newcommand\de\delta$For each $i\in[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$, let $X_{i,1},\dots,X_{i,n_i}$ be iid random variables with mean $x$ and variance $\si_i^2$. Let
\begin{equation*}
    Y_i:=\frac1{n_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}X_{i,j}. 
\end{equation*}
Then, by Chebyshev's inequality, for any real $\ep>0$,
\begin{equation*}
    p_i:=P(|Y_i-x|<\ep)\ge q_i:=1-\frac{\si_i^2}{\ep^2n_i}. \tag{0}
\end{equation*}

Let now
\begin{equation*}
    V:=\sum_{i=1}^k V_i,
\end{equation*}
where
$V_i:=1(|Y_i-x|<\ep)$, so that $V_i$ takes values in the set $\{0,1\}$ and $EV_i=p_i$. By [Chernoff's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)), for any $t\in[0,1]$
\begin{equation*}
    P(V\le(1-t)\mu)\le e^{-\mu t^2/3},\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \mu:=\sum_{i=1}^k EV_i=\sum_{i=1}^k p_i. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, for
\begin{equation*}
    Z:=\text{median}(Y_1,\dots,Y_k),
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
    P(|Z-x|>\ep)\le P(V\le k/2). 
\end{equation*}
So, by (1),
\begin{equation*}
    P(|Z-x|>\ep)\le\exp\Big\{-\frac{(\mu-k/2)^2}{3\mu}\Big\}. 
\end{equation*}
The latter expression is decreasing in $\mu\ge k/2$. So, in view of (0) and (2),
\begin{equation*}
    P(|Z-x|>\ep)\le\exp\Big\{-\frac{(\nu-k/2)^2}{3\nu}\Big\}, \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation}
    \nu:=\sum_{i=1}^k q_i=(1-c)k \tag{4}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation*}
    c:=\frac1{\ep^2k}\,\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\si_i^2}{n_i}, \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
provided that $c\le1/2$ (so that $\mu\ge\nu\ge k/2$).
Since the bound in (3) is decreasing in $\nu\ge k/2$, we want to make $\nu$ as large as possible, that is, to make $c$ as small as possible. It is easy to see that $c$ is minimized in positive real $n_1,\dots,n_k$ given
\begin{equation*}
    N:=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i
\end{equation*}
if the $n_i$'s are proportional to the corresponding $\si_i$'s. So, neglecting, for simplicity of writing, the fact that the $n_i$'s are integers, we get the optimal choice of the $n_i$'s:
\begin{equation*}
    n_i=\frac{\si_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^k\si_i'}\,N. 
\end{equation*}
So, by (3)--(5),
\begin{equation*}
    P(|Z-x|>\ep)\le\exp\Big\{-\frac{(1-c-1/2)^2}{3(1-c)}\,k\Big\},
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
    c=\frac{\Big(\sum_{i=1}^k\si_i\Big)^2}{\ep^2kN}=\frac{k\bar\si^2}{\ep^2N}, \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \bar\si:=\frac1k\,\sum_{i=1}^k\si_i. 
\end{equation*}
Taking $N=4k\bar\si^2/\ep^2$, we get $c=1/4$. So, to get
\begin{equation*}
    P(|Z-x|>\ep)\le\de,
\end{equation*}
it is enough to have $k\asymp\ln\frac1\de$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    N\asymp\frac{\bar\si^2}{\ep^2}\,\ln\frac1\de.  \tag{7}
\end{equation*}

---

In the special case when $\si_i=\si$ for all $i$, we get $\bar\si=\si$, so that estimate (7) is a generalization of your special-case estimate. (Of course, in $\Pr[|Z-\mathbb E[Z]|\ge \epsilon]\le \delta$, you wanted to write $x$ in place of $\mathbb E[Z]$.)

---

If, as you said in your comment, you have no control over the $n_i$'s, but only can choose them to be equal to one another as in your post, so that $n_i=h$ for some $h$ and all $i$, then only a small adjustment of what is written above is needed. Indeed, then, again in view of (5), formula (6) is replaced by
\begin{equation*}
    c=\frac1{\ep^2kh}\,\sum_{i=1}^k\si_i^2=\frac{\tilde\si^2}{\ep^2h}=\frac{k\tilde\si^2}{\ep^2N}, \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
where $\tilde\si^2:=\frac1k\,\sum_{i=1}^k\si_i^2$ and
$N=kh$ is the total sample size. Correspondingly, $\bar\si^2$ in (7) will be replaced by the somewhat greater quantity $\tilde\si^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A potential problem I'm seeing is that we do not have control over the $n_i$'s (e.g., I may have only one estimator with variance $\sigma^2_i$) and then the bound on $p_i$ may be smaller than $0$.
I think we may need to average over estimators with different variance, which is what I'm curios about how to do correctly.

Comment: @MA : In your post, you gave no indication that the sample sizes cannot be chosen freely for each $i$. To the contrary, you did choose your sample $h$ (the same for all $i$) to be just what you needed, depending on $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The target setting is one where you have a sequence of independent estimators such that $Var[X_i]\le Var[X_j]$ for $i \le j$. In the example, I said that if all variances are the same, we can use the median trick, and asked what to do if the variances are not necessarily the same.

Comment: @MA : That your variances are ordered does not matter at all. Also, I did show what to do when the variances are not necessarily the same. Now I have also done it when all the $n_i$'s are equal to the same $h$, just as in your post.

Comment: Sorry again for the misunderstanding. In my settings, I do not necessarily have $h$ estimators with the same variance. This was an example when all estimators had the same variance. Think, for example, of $\forall i: \sigma^2_i=\log(i+1)$. The question then is how can we aggregate them to get an $\epsilon,\delta$ bound.

Comment: @MA : OK, can you just state, formally and completely, what you need?